# Need help understanding what is going on in JQuery's noConflict() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking at the source code of [this site](http://www.stpiusx.org/page.cfm?p=1408) and trying to figure out how a part of the Javascript works because I want to copy their expanding list functionary (e.g. "WHEN & WHERE CAN I TURN IN MY SOLD TICKETS & MONEY") into my site.

Lines 74-75 of the source code are

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://newjs.finalsite.com/150409/javascript/jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript"> var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); </script>
```

which basically sets `$j` to whatever the function `noConflict()` returns.

Then, at the bottom of the code, they include the JS file http://newjs.finalsite.com/150409/javascript/pages/multicontent/multi_expand.js, which consists of the function

```
$j(function(){
    if(clickToClose){
        $j('.mcExpandingList').accordion({
            collapsible:'true',
            autoHeight: false
        });
        if(!mc_viewOption1){ $j('.mcExpandingList').accordion( 'option', 'active', false ); }
    }else{
        $j('.mcExpandingList').addClass('ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons');

        $j('.mcExpandingList h4').addClass('ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all')
        .prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>')
        .hover(function(){ $j(this).toggleClass('ui-state-hover') })
        .click(function(){
            $j(this).toggleClass('ui-state-active ui-corner-top ui-corner-all');
            $j(this).next().toggle('blind');
            $j(this).find('span').eq(0).toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s');
            return false;
        });

        $j('.contentElement').addClass('ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom').css('display','none');

        if (mc_viewOption1) {
            $j('.mcExpandingList h4').eq(0).toggleClass('ui-state-active ui-corner-top ui-corner-all');
            $j('.mcExpandingList h4').eq(0).next().show();
            $j('.mcExpandingList h4').eq(0).find('span').eq(0).addClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s');
        };
    }
});
```

which, as I understand, is passing an anonymous function to the `noConflict()` object that was returned, which gives me the idea that `$j` is itself a function that does something. But I'm a little confused about how that attaches the above function as a `click` event to the expanding list links. Does anyone here understand it, and if so, can you explain it to me?

Comment: This is what `jQuery.noConflict()` does: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: Thanks, DCoder. But what does it mean to pass an anonymous function to jQuery, that is, what does $j(function() { ... }) do?

Comment: That is document ready http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When jQuery is included it stores whatever value `window.$` previously had.

When we call `$j = jQuery.noConflict` is returns the value of `window.$` to its previous state. This is useful if you for example where using Prototype which also uses the shortcut `$`.

It also returns a new alias so that we can refer to jQuery by `$j`.

If you wish to adapt `multi_expand.js`, with an custom aliased jQuery without `jQuery.noConflict` the simplest way is by using a anonymous function.

```
(function($j){
  // $j is jQuery
}(jQuery));
```

Or you can change the first row to read:

```
jQuery(function($j){ 
  // $j is jQuery
```

Which basically means; when the document is ready, run this function, with jQuery as $j.